# Timeout Deleting a Single mySQL row?

Tags: mysql

I switched my organization's website from using MS Access to mySQL to try to improve the performance and it made it much worse.

I have a tiny table, with under 5,000 rows of data and I am trying to delete a single row from that table with the following statement:

```
DELETE FROM club_rosters WHERE player_id = " & tPlayerID & " AND club_id =" & cClubId & ";
```

This code is running from an ASP page.

The error message is as follows:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.6.40-84.0-56-log]Lost connection to MySQL server during query

/grassroots/clubs/admin/admPlayerMove.asp, line 126
```

I don't understand how this could timeout deleting a single row (the combination of player and club is unique in this table) using the primary key.

This is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE club_rosters
(club_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
player_id MEDIUMINT DEFAULT NULL,
roster_type_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
is_in_results TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
updated_at DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

ALTER TABLE club_rosters ADD PRIMARY KEY (club_id, player_id);
ALTER TABLE club_rosters ADD INDEX (roster_type_id);
```

Comment: Does 't look like a design issue, you lost connection during your query. Try the same query without using ODBC

Comment: Which version of ASP are you talking about? Also, it's a little unclear how this fact relates to the question (since you're only asking about SQL), so I edited that tag out for now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is very strange, and I have no idea why it works, but inserting a space after the second equals sign does this trick.

So I changed the code from:

```
DELETE FROM club_rosters WHERE player_id = " & tPlayerID & " AND club_id =" & cClubId & ";
```

To:

```
DELETE FROM club_rosters WHERE player_id = " & tPlayerID & " AND club_id = " & cClubId & ";
```